# How do I trigger socket io events for testing purposes?

Tags: pytest, python-asyncio, python-unittest, python-socketio

### Background

I wanted to write a unit test for `connect` on the code excerpts below given the following assumptions:

1. When `AsyncClient` is instantiated, `self.io.connected` and
   `self.conn_established` are `False`
2. At the first `connect` call,
   we assert that `self.io.connect` is called (ideally,
   `self.io.connect` should be mocked here)
3. When `connect` event is
   emitted `self.conn_established` is set to True (since we mock
   `self.io.connect`, then we'll need to mock the triggering of the
   `connect` event)

```py
class AsyncClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn_established = False
        self.io = socketio.AsyncClient()

        @self.io.event
        def connect():
            self.connection_established = True

    async def connect(self):
        while not self.io.connected:
            await self.io.connect(endpoint)
        
        while not self.conn_established:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

---

#### What I had tried

I was able to write a mock for `io.connect`, but I'm stuck with triggering the socketio connect event:

```
@pytest.fixture
def async_client():
    yield AsyncClient()


class AsyncMock(mock.MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_connect(async_client):
    def mock_successful_conn(*args, **kwargs):
        async_client.io.connected = True
        # how do I trigger the following?
        async_client.io.trigger_event("connect")

    # mock io.connect
    async_client.io.connect = AsyncMock(spec=async_client.io.connect, side_effect=mock_successful_conn)
    await async_client.connect()
```

---

#### Questions

1. How do I write the unit tests for the above?
2. Is there a way to trigger socketio events for testing purposes?

Thanks! Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered creating a mock version of the `async_client.io.event` decorator that captures the event, and a mock version of the `asyncio_client.io.connect` method that just calls the function that was captured earlier?

Comment: hi, can you clarify what you meant by calling the function that was captured? do you mean calling the event handler function (eg: `connect`) directly?

Comment: Yes. The mock decorator saves the function, and the mock connect calls it.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks to @Miguel's suggestion, I was able to mock the triggering of the event by calling the event handler function directly.

We can get them by accessing the client's handlers which are first indexed by namespace, and then indexed by the event handler's name.

So in my case, I can get the `connect` event handler by doing this:

```
connect_handler = tunnel_client.io.handlers["/"]["connect"]
connect_handler()
```